# Linq @ Where clause with multiple condition

Tags: linq

this is my export ui

[image]

this is my code:

```
var wrlist = db.Tbl_WorkRequest.ToList().Where(c => c.WR_Status == wrstatus &&
                                                    (wrtype.Length != 0) &&
                                                    c.WR_Family == wrfamily &&
                                                    wrfamily.Length!=0)
                                        .Select(d => new {
                                            WR_Title = d.WR_Title.ToString(),
                                            WR_Type = d.WR_Type.ToString(),
                                            WR_Family = d.WR_Family.ToString(),
                                            WR_Status = d.WR_Status.ToString(),
                                            WR_LocationAsset = d.WR_LocationAsset.ToString(),
                                            WR_AssetName = d.WR_AssetName.ToString(),
                                            WR_Requestor = d.WR_Requestor.ToString()
                                        });
```

the problem is if I only choose zone in dropdownlist:family it generates correct list.
but when I choose dropdownlist:family&status it generates nothing.

this is the table:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure Status value (`wrstattus`) that you send from UI matches with database? Did you check generated SQL?

Comment: What is zone? What is dropdownlist:family? What is dropdownlist:family&status and what does that mean? Why are you using `ToList` before your `Where` which pulls your entire table into memory? What types are your `WR_` fields that you need to put `ToString()` on them?

Comment: Why are you comparing against `wrstatus` but then testing `wrtype.Length`?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to check each filter criteria and add the appropriate filter, then convert to a list:

```
var wrq = db.Tbl_WorkRequest.AsQueryable();
if (wrstatus.Length > 0)
    wrq = wrq.Where(wr => wr.WR_Status == wrstatus);
if (wrfamily.Length > 0)
    wrq = wrq.Where(wr => wr.WR_Family == wrfamily);

var wrlist = wrq.Select(d => new {
                    WR_Title = d.WR_Title.ToString(),
                    WR_Type = d.WR_Type.ToString(),
                    WR_Family = d.WR_Family.ToString(),
                    WR_Status = d.WR_Status.ToString(),
                    WR_LocationAsset = d.WR_LocationAsset.ToString(),
                    WR_AssetName = d.WR_AssetName.ToString(),
                    WR_Requestor = d.WR_Requestor.ToString()
                })
                .ToList();
```